# how to clear list of email in yopmail.com

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hi i have scenario using selenium need to automate creating yopmail user account so for every next iteration if i try to create new account I need to clear the email which i have entered previously.so for this i have tried few options which i read ur blogs but its not helping much...
options tried 
1.element.clear() method
2.using keys select text and delete.

I dont need the above ways please let me know the third way which we directly clear entire history usng option specified as "clearlist' in yopmail drop down.

issue: when i click() mail box icon the drop down is disappearing due to this am getting elementnot visible exception.

code which using

```
FirefoxDriver d = new FirefoxDriver();
    d.get("http://yopmail.com");
    try{
    d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login']")).sendKeys("mpqa");
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='f']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/input")).click();  

       Thread.sleep(1000);
       WebElement mailboxIcon=d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menucpt']/ul/li[1]/center/span"));          
       Thread.sleep(1000);

    Actions builder = new Actions(d);  
    builder.moveToElement(mailboxIcon).build().perform();
    mailboxIcon.click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(d, 15); 
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='f']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")));      

       WebElement clearList=d.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='menucpt']/ul/li[3]/a"));
       clearList.click();
```

please check the attached immage
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB1MC.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This happened because your xpath is wrong.

```
WebElement mailboxIcon=d.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='butcpt']"));
```

Replace it and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

For clear the list use this code. It will surely work for you

```
 driver.get("http://yopmail.com");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login']")).sendKeys("si");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='f']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/input")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='butcpt']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Clear list ")).click();
```

AND If you want to clear the inbox then use the below code. It will work for you.`

```
    try{
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='login']")).sendKeys("si");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='f']/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/input")).click(); 
driver.switchTo().frame("ifinbox");// Actually the inbox mails are showing in an iFrame so first we have to switch to that iFrame to perform the further action.
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='e0']")).click();// click on the select mail icon.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/a")).click();// click on the delete
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Empty Inbox")).click();// click on the Empty Inbox.
}
```